# Automatic naming in glossary

Tags: glossaries

I'd like the following result in a glossary: The name of a glossary entry  to be automatically  the number of the exercise and simultaneously  this exersise's number to appear in glossary. 
Below, in a minimal working example (XeTeX) the name of the glossary entry (cycled with red in picture) appears next to exersise's number, i.e. **Exercise 1.1** *1.1*. Is it possible the second *1.1* (cycled with red in picture) not appearing?
Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}[section]

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{a}{name={1.1},sort={a},description={SolverA}}
\newglossaryentry{b}{name={1.2},sort={b},description={SolverB}}

\begin{document}

\section{Exersises}

\begin{solution}\gls{a}
Suppose that $a>b$ and $a+2b<2$, then...
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}\gls{b}
Suppose that $c<d$ and $c^2+d^2>1$, then...
\end{solution}

\printglossary[type=main,nopostdot,style=mcolindex, title={the solvers}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:11Fev2020** I found a solution via hyperref package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, filecolor=black,     
 urlcolor=black}

\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}[section]

\let\origref\autoref
\def\autoref#1{\textbf{\origref{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\section{Exersises}

\begin{solution}\label{sol:1.1}
Suppose that $a>b$ and $a+2b<2$, then...
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}\label{sol:1.2}
Suppose that $c<d$ and $c^2+d^2>1$, then...
\end{solution}

\section*{the solvers}

\autoref{sol:1.1} SolverA \pageref{sol:1.1}\\
\autoref{sol:1.2} SolverB \pageref{sol:1.2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you are not using glossaries package as intended. If you need to reference theorems, there are better options.

Comment: @Tomáš Kruliš You're right! I've edited my post giving  a solution via hyperref package.